# Less than 10k and saw a deleted post

Tags: support, status-norepro, deleted-posts

I haven't hit 10k on Stack Overflow yet, so I was quite surprised when hitting a link to a question that it turns out to be deleted, but yet the content was shown (all in one box).  Besides the content box was shown this message (names edited out):

[image: deleted message]

Could someone please explain what's happening here, and if there is more to come?

Comment: I can't help but notice the BGR subpixel anti-aliasing in your screenshot.

Comment: That smells pretty odd...do you have any AddOns/PlugIns/UserScripts in place?

Comment: What is the link to the aforementioned question?

Comment: @amanaP I'm going to guess at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197952

Comment: ~6k and shows the normal error page to me.

Comment: Does a refresh display it again?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, nothing SO related, just basic stuff like adbocker.

Comment: @Oded, I'm now at work, and don't see it here, won't be able to test at home again until tonight.

Comment: Since no one can't seem to reproduce, I vote it as Too Localized.

Comment: This will still be useful to SO staff (if it was a debug message from the Matrix that somehow slipped through). I'd say leave it to them to close

Comment: I'm with Pekka on this - if there is a bug, is better to ensure that someone in the staff can see this. Should we also retag the question with Bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have [Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks)' [deleted question viewer](https://gist.github.com/1361876/9c54b1dcd0b08eaff425ebaab2fd9c9dbb326168#file-deleted-user-js) userscript installed. According to the [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer-broken) post, it's broken, but I guess it circumstantially worked for you.

It prints out the text you're seeing:

```
print("Deleted post detected. Loading post content...");
// ...
```

Comment: I guess that could be, I'll check the greasemonkey when I get home.

Comment: I guess @jeremy needs to be added to the wheel of blame...

Comment: Yep, that was it.